# Create a vector of factors with multiple level

Tags: r, for-loop, vector

I am trying to write an R program that can create a vector.

Suppose I have 3 factors (X with levels 1,2,3, Y with levels 1,2, and Z with level 1,2,3,4). If I want to represent them in a contingency table there are 3x2x4=24 cells. (for example, (111, 112, 121, 222) are typical cells).

I want to write a for loop that the output is a vector of all cells. that means the output is a vector of length 24.

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and show the expected output for the same. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

```
vector1 <- factor(x = c(1,2,3))
vector2 <- factor(x = c(1,2))
vector3 <- factor(x = c(1,2,3,4,3,2))

df1 <- expand.grid(levels(vector1),levels(vector2),levels(vector3))

results <- paste0(df1$Var1,df1$Var2,df1$Var3)

factor(results)
```

Comment: It is hard to be more efficient than this but if you really need the loop, just do loop vector1 - vector 2, then use the result with vector 3

Comment: Like a general program that can take any number of factors at any level. Here I used  3 factors for convenience.

Comment: That is why you need to write a reproducible example, it is hard to follow just text

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution using `lapply` :

#### create dummy data and assign it to a list

```
set.seed(10)

listofvectors<-list(
factor(sample(1:3,20, replace = TRUE)),
factor(sample(1:2,10, replace = TRUE)), 
factor(sample(1:4,15, replace = TRUE))
)
```

#### generate a table of combinations

```
combinations <-expand.grid(lapply(listofvectors, levels))
```

#### combine row-wise then create vector

```
unlist(do.call("paste0", combinations))
```